# Difference in where clause beetwen JPQL and CriteriaBuilder

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink, jpql, criteria-api

I have two separate entity class: Job and JobOrgUnitCfg
Below I put two pieces of code make this same select on that objects.

First query in JPQL:

```
    Query jobOrgUnitCfgQuery = entityManager.createQuery(
            "SELECT c FROM JobOrgUnitCfg c WHERE c.orgId = :orgId and c.schedulerNextActivation < current_timestamp and c.active = :active and " +
            " not exists (SELECT j  FROM Job j WHERE j.orderId = c.orderId and j.orgId = c.orgId and j.status <> :jobStatus)");

    jobOrgUnitCfgQuery.setParameter("orgId", orgId);
    jobOrgUnitCfgQuery.setParameter("jobStatus", JobStatusEnum.End);
    jobOrgUnitCfgQuery.setParameter("active", Boolean.TRUE);
    return jobOrgUnitCfgQuery.getResultList();
```

and second query build with CriteriaBuilder:

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<JobOrgUnitCfg> criteria = cb.createQuery(JobOrgUnitCfg.class);
    Root<JobOrgUnitCfg> jobOrgUnitCfgRoot = criteria.from(JobOrgUnitCfg.class);

    Subquery<Job> subquery = criteria.subquery(Job.class);
    Root<Job> jobRoot = subquery.from(Job.class);

    subquery.where(
            cb.and(
                    cb.equal(jobRoot.get(Job_.orderId), jobOrgUnitCfgRoot.get(JobOrgUnitCfg_.orderId)),
                    cb.equal(jobRoot.get(Job_.orgId), jobOrgUnitCfgRoot.get(JobOrgUnitCfg_.orgId)),
                    cb.not(cb.equal(jobRoot.get(Job_.status), JobStatusEnum.End))
            )
    );

    Predicate where = cb.and(cb.equal(jobOrgUnitCfgRoot.get(JobOrgUnitCfg_.orgId), orgId),
            cb.lessThan(jobOrgUnitCfgRoot.get(JobOrgUnitCfg_.schedulerNextActivation), cb.currentTimestamp()),
            cb.equal(jobOrgUnitCfgRoot.get(JobOrgUnitCfg_.active), Boolean.TRUE),
            cb.not(cb.exists(subquery))
    );

    criteria.where(where);
    TypedQuery<JobOrgUnitCfg> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteria);
    return query.getResultList();
```

First generate wrong where clause (duplicate table S_JOBS_ORG_UNIT_CFG inside subselect):

```
SELECT ... FROM S_JOBS_ORG_UNIT_CFG t0 
WHERE ((((t0.ORG_ID = ?) AND (t0.SCHEDULER_NEXT_ACTIVATION < SYSDATE)) AND (t0.ACTIVE = ?)) 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ? FROM S_JOBS_ORG_UNIT_CFG t2, S_JOBS t1 WHERE ((((t1.ORDER_ID = t2.ORDER_ID) AND (t1.ORG_ID = t2.ORG_ID)) AND (t1.STATUS <> ?)) AND (t0.ORDER_ID = t2.ORDER_ID))) )
```

sql from Criteriabuilder is right:

```
SELECT ... FROM S_JOBS_ORG_UNIT_CFG t0 
WHERE ((((t0.ORG_ID = ?) AND (t0.SCHEDULER_NEXT_ACTIVATION < SYSDATE)) AND (t0.ACTIVE = ?)) 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ? FROM S_JOBS t1 WHERE (((t1.ORDER_ID = t0.ORDER_ID) AND (t1.ORG_ID = t0.ORG_ID)) AND NOT ((t1.STATUS = ?)))) )
```

Can someone explain me what is wrong in my JPQL ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it was just a bug in JPQL that added the extra table join.  It should not affect the result.

It should be fixed in the latest release or build of EclipseLink.

Comment: Thanks. I checked with last released eclipselink version 2.3.0 and isn't fixed yet.